# ALL-keyword on Advanced search - reduces hits - workaround?

Tags: search, search-scope

we have a customer reacting about the "all these words" feature in advanced search. If you search for a word in "simple search" you get for instance 34 hits. If you search for the same word in advanced, you get the ALL({word}) search query. This reduces the number of hits to exactly 1, as the ALL() means the exact word as far as I have managed to see.

Is there any way to not have the "ALL"-limitation in advanced search? So that it searches in the same way, but you can then filter via your own limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this: I added a script-file, put it on the "Advanced search" page using content editor web part, and added a function called ComposeTextSectionQuery with a signature of ComposeTextSectionQuery(elements) in this file. This effectively replaced the original function with the same name, and then removed the "ALL" keyword like this:

```
    function ComposeTextSectionQuery(elements) {
    // Replace of original function!
    var allQuery = elements.AndQueryTextBox.value != '' ? elements.AndQueryTextBox.value : '';
    var phraseQuery = elements.PhraseQueryTextBox.value != '' ? enquote(elements.PhraseQueryTextBox.value): '';
    var anyQuery = elements.OrQueryTextBox.value != '' ? 'ANY(' + elements.OrQueryTextBox.value + ')': '';
    var noneQuery = elements.NotQueryTextBox.value ? 'NONE(' + elements.NotQueryTextBox.value + ')' : '';
    if (phraseQuery == '' && anyQuery == '' && noneQuery == '' && allQuery == '') 
    {
        allQuery = 'ALL()';
    }

    return ConcatenateQueryParts(allQuery, phraseQuery, anyQuery, noneQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the query from the advanced search is passed through URL, using JavaScript code you can grab the URL and change the query.

for example instead of:

```
http://myServer/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=ALL(yourword)
```

with some JavaScript code:

```
//var url=window.location;
var url="http://myServer/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=ALL(yourword)";
var str1 = url.replace("ALL(","");
var str2 = str1.replace(")","")
alert(str2);
```

change it to:

```
http://myServer/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=yourword
```

Comment: Where would I put this JavaScript-code to get it to work?

Comment: you can hook to the click event using JQuery, so when the user clicks on the search button in advanced search, you can use the code above to change the url.

Comment: This would probably work, but I found an easier solution. I added a script-file, put it on the "Advanced search" page using content editor web part, and added a function called ComposeTextSectionQuery in this file. This effectively replaced the original function with the same name, and then removed the "ALL" keyword